# Protobuf - builder doesn't exists?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm using the protobuf example ( for C# and java) :

The `proto` file

```
package tutorial;

option java_package = "com.example.tutorial";
option java_outer_classname = "AddressBookProtos";

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}

message AddressBook {
  repeated Person person = 1;
}
```

I already have a `Person` object :

```
Person john = Person
            .newBuilder()
            .setId(1234)
            .setName("John Doe")
            .setEmail("jdoe@example.com")
            .addPhone(
                    Person.PhoneNumber.newBuilder().setNumber("555-4321")
                            .setType(Person.PhoneType.HOME)).build();
```

Now let's suppose Ive read that object from a stream( working fine) , and now I want to update the Email :

The example [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated?csw=1#message) says to :

[image]

So I tried to get the email builder but I only see this :

[image]

**Question**

How can I edit this person of myne , and why does the exact code , doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email is not defined as a sub message in your proto file, is a String.

`Protoc` generates the messages as java classes, each generated class has a `Builder` sub class who extends `com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.Builder` and implements all necesary methods to work and the builder is accesible via the appropiate getter.

That's the reason why you cant get the PhoneNumber builder

```
john.toBuilder().getPhoneBuilder(index);
```

and set the PhoneNumber fields, because is defined as a sub message and has his own Builder

```
  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }
```

and you can not get the email Builder, because the email does not exists as message sub class (with his own builder), is defined as a String and the builder is the Person Class builder

```
optional string email = 3;
```

If you want to change the email you can do

```
john.toBuilder().setEmail("jdoe@example.com").buid();
```

It is a bit confused but hope this helps.

Comment: From my testing it should be `john=john.toBuilder().setEmail("jdoe@example.com").build()`